# Adding Silverlight Thumbnail

Tags: silverlight, thumbnails

I am working on silverlight application and I wanted to know how I can add Thumbnail 
into different different view.

Basically this application is Photo Editing application, so what I am trying to do is 
once my layout is ready i mean one sheet inside the images its my blank sheet.

so this view I want to see in a different different thumbnail.

thanks...

Comment: This is *way* off-topic for this site; it belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I flagged this post off-topic.

Comment: I have to agree with Stan, this is a software development question, not a photography or photographic editing question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeff Prosise blogged a thumbnailer [here](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/12/17/silverlight-s-big-image-problem-and-what-you-can-do-about-it.aspx).  The basic principle is to take another `WritableBitmap` and use its `Render` method to render your image with a scale transform.  You can then use this new `WritableBitmap` as the source for you thumbnail image control.